# Is there a way to defer firing jquery.ajax call to allow further modifying its settings by other functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm constructing a jquery.ui widget, which needs to call a backend service via ajax. However, not all settings are available when invoking the `$.post()` in that particular widget, i.e. the `post` needs to be passed to other functions by the `_trigger()` signal, and use other cooperating widgets to complete all the settings, only then it can be sent to the backend.

It's something like this:

```
$.widget('widget1', {
   drilldown: function(){
       var pseudocode_variable = $.post('backend_service', _incomplete_settings, callback);
       this._trigger('request_drilldown', event, [pseudocode_variable]);
   },
   ...
});

$.widget('widget2', {...complete_ajaxsettings_here, then fire...});
```

I've looked up in the jquery documentation, but didn't get anywhere. Could someone more informed give a direction whether such idea is implementable? Thanks.

Comment: Then don't call $.post till you have all the settings, pass the arguments forward, store them somewhere, or use it in the callback

Comment: @PatrickEvans But I have some logic inside the `widget1` that's contigent on the `$.post` success. It would be awkward to put that logic elsewhere.

Comment: Well I guess the bottle neck here is not in `$.post()`, but in the mechanism where when you `_trigger()` an event from a jquery ui widget, you cannot get any direct feedback on that triggering. Any suggestion that can work around it? thx